# C# WindowsFormApplication webBrowser loading time

Tags: c#, page-load-time

I'm making a simple search engine speed comparison, and so I implemented this code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(webBrowser1.StatusText == "Done"))
        i1++;
    else
    {
        textBox2.Text = (i1).ToString() + " ms";
    }
}
```

so I type my search subject in textBox1 and press a button to do the search in 4 different webBrowsers each of them uses a search engine (google, bing, yahoo and duckduckgo) and I want the time elapsed searching to view in a textBox beside the webBrowser, the code I implemented doesn't seem to work probably it shows the result a lot faster than the page finish loading.

Comment: I believe that when the page finishes loading just means that the result has been obtained from the server, it doesn't mean that the page has finished rendering on the control. What are you really after, the results returned from the server or the time it takes for them to be graphically displayed to the user?

Comment: Well I think that I got neither of those two in my code because the result displays before rendering completes and when I compare it with the result that google gives on it's search page it doesn't match. But what I really want is the servers result

Comment: If you're doing speed comparisons, try using a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).